# Generate subroutines/functions general comments in Excel VBA editor

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way to automatically generate functions and subroutines general comments in Excel VBA editor like we it can be done through Eclipse (for Java, not to be misunderstood)?

Comment: I've never come across one but you could build it yourself (using VBE) and market it!

Comment: Good idea, but I make money with other technologies. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not natively. The [MZ-Tools](http://www.mztools.com/v3/mztools3.aspx) add-in can automatically add header comments to functions/subs and entire modules though (along with a ton of other handy features).